# How to use `apply` and a function to loop through df row values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this table

```
well        MRPW1      MRPW2      MRPW3      MRPW4       MRPW5      MRPW6      MRPW7      MRPW8      MRPW9     MRPW10  MRPW11  MRPW12

well1        NaN        NaN        NaN   0.115293   76.652246  67.545672  47.503333  56.198555  47.008101  44.703443     NaN     NaN
well2        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  112.594625  79.635218  54.754644  72.015028  82.042539  72.871044     NaN     NaN
well3        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN        NaN   1.607063  89.893566  90.315224  85.814613     NaN     NaN
```

I used this code. I need to loop through each row values and produce a number that get assigned to a new column. **summation is only an example here but I want to do another calculation with this looping. It is the looping that I want to achieve here.**

```
df=df.fillna(0)


def calcMRPW(row):
    sum=0
    for x in row:
        #sum is only an example. what I really need is to loop through the row values.
        sum=x+sum
    return sum


 df["sum"]=df.loc[:,"MRPW1":"MRPW10"].apply(calcMRPW)

print(df.head())
```

this is the result

```
well       MRPW1      MRPW2      MRPW3      MRPW4       MRPW5      MRPW6      MRPW7      MRPW8      MRPW9     MRPW10  MRPW11  MRPW12  sum
well1     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.115293   76.652246  67.545672  47.503333  56.198555  47.008101  44.703443     0.0     0.0  NaN
well2     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  112.594625  79.635218  54.754644  72.015028  82.042539  72.871044     0.0     0.0  NaN
well3     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000    0.000000   0.000000   1.607063  89.893566  90.315224  85.814613     0.0     0.0  NaN
```

the product from the function is `NaN`. How can I make this work?

Comment: I suggest to edit your post since people just jump at the sum example you have picked and ignore that you wrote it is just an example but you are actually going to apply a different function

Comment: @Sammy I did that already both in text and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop accross a row you need to add `axis=1`:

```py
df['sum'] = df.loc[:,"MRPW1":"MRPW10"].apply(calcMRPW,axis=1)
```

Comment: summation is only an example. now i know what I was missing, adding `axis=1` to `.apply(`